# Strange behavior with error java.security.cert.CertificateParsingException

Tags: eclipse, maven, tomcat, ssl

I'm encountering some problems with SSL and Java.
I will try to be quick and clear.

It's a Java Webapp that has to read emails and make stuff with these emails.
I have a certificate to connect to the Mailbox.

```
Technicals info : 
Eclipse : Luna
Project : compiled with JDK 1.6
Tomcat : pluged with Eclipse, launched with JDK 1.6
Tomcat on Test server : launched with JDK 1.6
Maven pom.xml : compiler plugin source/target : 1.6
```

Here is my problem :

When I checkout for the first time the project (via Git) or when I compile it with maven with :

```
mvm clean compile eclipse:eclipse
```

I got a project that is "ok" in Eclipse and compiles. 
Ok means for me : sources compile, api are ok, library is ok (JDK 1.6), webapp is running ok on Tomcat.

Then If I try to read mails, I got this error :

```
java.net.SocketException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: 
Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, 
provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.DefaultSSLContextImpl)

DEBUG: getProvider() returning provider protocol=imaps;     type=javax.mail.Provider$Type@7df92e01; class=com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore; vendor=Sun     Microsystems, Inc
DEBUG: mail.imap.fetchsize: 16384
keyStore is : 
keyStore type is : jks
keyStore provider is : 
init keystore
init keymanager of type SunX509
trustStore is: D:\Workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\leaseit dev\WEB-INF\classes\certif\client-truststore.jks
trustStore type is : jks
trustStore provider is : 
init truststore
default context init failed:     java.security.cert.CertificateParsingException:java.io.IOException: DerInputStream.getLength(): lengthTag=50, too big.
```

If then, I just "clean" my project with Eclipse (with Options --> Clean), then, I don't have the SSL problem. On my Test server, I always have the problem as I deploy it with maven.

I think this is a very strange behavior and I can't find where is the problem.
I've read a lot to threads on the web (including Stackoverflow), I've checked if I have the jsse.jar, I put the javax.mail to debug, I've tried to debug it but the error appears way too far in the code … :-(

> Strange fact : I have an other web app that shares all the "reading
>   mail" part and I don't have the problem. But I am not 100% sure that
>   they have the same environment settings.

I don't want to believe that my certificate has a problem because it comes from an other app that is ok and if it can be read if I clean my project.

Questions :

- Which tests do you suggest to me ?
- Why a simple "clean" rids off my problem ?
- Is it related to my jdk or my certificate that is the same than the other app ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect your client-truststore.jks is corrupted by maven filtering. Try deactivating it in your pom with the following maven-resources-plugin configuration.

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.6</version>
   <configuration>
       <nonFilteredFileExtensions>
           <nonFilteredFileExtension>jks</nonFilteredFileExtension>
       </nonFilteredFileExtensions>
   </configuration>
</plugin>
```